# why <f:ajax> tags doesnt work in JSP with JSF2.0

Tags: jsp, jsf-2

I am working with JSF2.0 and I want to make JSP page with with ajax-enabled component  which is inbuilt component in JSF2.0 and i did following coding for that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>        
        <h3>JSF 2.0 + Ajax Hello World Example</h3>

        <h:form>
           <h:inputText id="sname" value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
           <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me">
             <f:ajax execute="sname" render="output" />
           </h:commandButton>

           <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.sayWelcome}" /></h2>    
        </h:form>             
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

Now,when i m trying to run this code i m getting following error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /TestAjax.jsp (line: 22, column: 7) No tag "ajax" defined in tag library imported with prefix "f"
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)

So,please help me how to solve it?And also help me that is  tag is allowed in JSP or not?
Thanks in advance

I have inclded following jar files:**jsf-api,jsf-impl,jstl-api-1.2,jstl-impl-1.2**

Answer (score 3):

Old JSP is not fully supported by JSF 2. All you get is JSF 1.2 fallback modus. You need its successor Facelets instead.

Rename `page.jsp` to `page.xhtml` and redeclare/rewrite the document as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
>
    <h:head>
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>JSF 2.0 + Ajax Hello World Example</h3>
        <h:form>
           <h:inputText id="sname" value="#{helloBean.name}" />
           <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me">
               <f:ajax execute="@form" render="output" />
           </h:commandButton>
           <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.sayWelcome}" /></h2>    
        </h:form>             
    </h:body>
</html>
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 Tutorial - Introduction to Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html)
- [Our JSF tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) (contains several good JSF 2 tutorial links)